# Restore gridview scroll position windows store app

Tags: vb.net, gridview, windows-store-apps

Hi i want to restore scroll position when navigating back, i have tried the following code but i gives me errors.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As NavigationEventArgs)

    Dim t As Item = DirectCast(ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values("scroll"), Item)
    FlavorGrid.ScrollIntoView(t)

End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedFrom(e As NavigationEventArgs)

    Dim t As Item = DirectCast(storeData.Collection.LastOrDefault(), Item)
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Clear()
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Add("scroll", scrollItem)

End Sub
```

The following are the errors that i get.
  1. type 'Item' is not defined 
  2.'FlavorGrid' is not declared. it maybe inaccessible due to its protection level
  3. 'scrollItem' is not declared. it maybe inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: at the top of the aspx page in the @Page directive set `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"`

Comment: @fnostro i'm using windows store app with vb.

Comment: ah - ok - actually you also said nav-back - not postback so wouldn't have helped regardless...maybe you can implement a third party like [**this**](http://mrcoles.com/blog/scroll-sneak-maintain-position-between-page-loads/)

Comment: @fnostro that's for desktop application, the app that i'm developing is for windows store.

Comment: yes - I understand that.  I was suggesting that a third part javascript library that is designed to maintain scroll position between navigation calls might be of some use.  VB.net and C#.net can both utilize JS/jQuery.  It might be worth looking into.

Comment: HTML/JS and XAML/C# are completely different worlds and other than some general logic and UI developer tricks - few things transition directly between different platorms.

Comment: @TankAmo Seems like you simply copied some code from someone else and the variables/elements simply don't exist in your app.